# Call UIButton AddTarget in the same class

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, addtarget

I have a simple view V and view controller C. The controller calls a separate class X that build a webview and a button to close the webview.

I instantiate class X (with a reference to view V) then call a method to attach both items (webview and items).

When i call the button addTarget method, it does not work. I want it to execute the closeAll method of the X class and not the closeAll method of the C controller.

I have tried hundreds of variants.

Here is (parts of) the code in C controller:

```
let parentView:UIView
...

@objc func closeAll() {
    print("Close webview, object")
}
```

and this in X class:

```
    ...
    let transparentButton = UIButton(frame: frame)
    transparentButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(self.overlayTransparency)
    transparentButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    transparentButton.alpha = 0.5
    transparentButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    transparentButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector("closeAll"), for: .touchUpInside)
    parentView.addSubview(transparentButton)
```

I have this in my C controller and it get called on click:

```
@objc func closeAll() {
    print("Close webview, main")
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where the code above is running, but you need to pass the instance of `X` as the target and your selector syntax isn't right (it's not a String): `transparentButton.addTarget(instanceOfX, action:#selector(X.closeAll), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: Thx for your answer. I tried
transparentButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(X.closeAll), for: .touchUpInside) without success. C.closeAll is still getting called.

Comment: Are you assigning the instance of X to a property of C?

Comment: No i don't. Actually X is part of a small framework and i want the implementation ans use of the class as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change self to instance of a class that you want it's method to be triggered

Comment: No. At run time it tries to find a closeAll method in the main controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert either of these into your class:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()
    transparentButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(closeAll),  for: .UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}

func closeAll(sender:AnyObject) {
    // your code
}
```

**OR**

```swift
@IBOutlet var btnStartJob: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad()    {  
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnStartJob.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeAll), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func closeAll(_ sender : UIButton) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Ok i will test that, but my X class is not a UIView. Will have to refactor a bit. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It didn't work. What id did is to subcass UIButton and i put the closeAll in that class.

Comment: can you explain me properly?. otherwise put your code i can check it.i will give you proper answer to you